# Explanation of 'Mean number of correct guesses' in a lottery game.

Tags: probability

I'm currently going through my Probability lecture notes and have reached a passage which talks about a lottery game with 6 balls selected out of 49. It then says:

```
Calculate the mean number of correct guesses that you’ll make.
```

I find the wording hard to understand anyway but... the solution is given as:

> Solution. Let X denote the number of correct guesses, then X = I1 + ... +I6 
>   where Ik = 1 or 0 according as your kth guess is correct or not. Each
>   guess has probability 6/49 of being correct, so E(Ik) = 1×6/49+0×43/49 = 6/49.
>
> EX = E(I1 + · · · + I6) = EI1 + · · · + EI6 = 6×$6/49$ = $36/49$ = 0.7347.

Why does each guess have probability 6/49 of being correct? Why not 6/49 then 5/48 etc... If anyone could help decode this I'm not sure if it's me misunderstanding but I would appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **could** calculate the mean number of correct guesses as follows. Let $X$ be the number of correct guesses. Calculate $\Pr(X=0)$, $\Pr(X=1)$, and so on up to $\Pr(X=6)$. Then calculate the expectation in the usual way.

However, the method of **indicator** random variables described in the post leads to a much simpler calculation. There are a number of cases where the probability distribution function is very difficult to get at, but indicator random variables work smoothly.

What may be contributing to your doubts is the feeling that if you know something about, for example, the value taken on by $I_1$, then you know something about $I_4$. That is true. It is equally true that if you know something about $I_4$, then you know something about $I_1$.

That intuition is perfectly correct. The $I_j$ all have the same distribution, but they are **not independent**. The beauty of the method is that this doesn't matter! The expectation of a sum of random variables is the sum of the expectations. The random variables don't need to be independent.

The reasoning that shows that for any $j$, $\Pr(I_j=1)=\frac{6}{49}$ has already been thoroughly described in other answers. Imagine that you shuffle your numbers and check, one after the other, whether the number is a winner. Since all shufflings are equally likely, the probability that the fourth number checked is a winner is exactly the same as the probability that the first number is a winner.

**Remark:** If the intuition about this is not yet clear, let us calculate, the **long way**, the probability that the second number is a winner.  This can happen in two ways: (i) the first is a winner **and** the second is a winner or (ii) the first is a loser and the second is a winner.

The probability of (i) is $\frac{6}{49}\cdot\frac{5}{48}$. The probability of (ii) is $\frac{43}{49}\cdot\frac{6}{48}$. Add and simplify. We get $\frac{6}{49}$. We could now use the same complicated method to find the probability that the third number is a winner. After dividing into $4$ cases, and calculating, we again get $\frac{6}{49}$. We can continue, with lengthier and lengthier calculations, getting, after simplification, $\frac{6}{49}$ each time.

The fact that we get $\frac{6}{49}$ each time sends a loud message: there must be a better way!

Comment: Thank you for answering so thoroughly! A lot clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Each individual guess has probability $\frac 6{49}$ of being correct if you don't consider whether the others are.  This is useful for evaluating the mean number or correct guesses, as they do.  You get $\frac 5{48}$ for the second guess *if you are given that the first one was correct*.  This is useful if you want to calculate the probability of getting them all correct.

Some would consider it obvious that the chance the second is correct is $\frac 6{49}$ if we ignore whether the first is correct (just swap the guesses), but we can calculate it if we want.  The chance the second is correct is $\frac 5{48}\cdot \frac 6{49} + \frac 6{48}\cdot\frac {43}{49}=\frac {30+258}{48\cdot 49}=\frac 6{49}$ where the first term computes the chance that both of the first two will be correct and the second computes the chance the first will miss and the second will be correct.

Comment: Your second paragraph makes it almost clear to me - but for some reason I can't accept that each pick has a 6/49 chance when you can't pick the same number twice... (I think I need a break)